# Why do I need a MySQL connector in Java?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

Always when I want to use a programme that is using a MySQL database, it forces me to install a MySQL connector or *mysql-connector-java.jar*.

Why do I need a MySQL connector and how does it work??

Comment: It's a Java application that needs to connect to a MySQL database. The connector is a library that enables this.

Comment: You can easily Google to get an answer to this, but the MySQL connector JAR contains all the logic/code which allows Java to talk to MySQL.  Example of what it does: It has logic which can map MySQL types to Java types and vice-versa.

Comment: @Phylogenesis so that means that java need to connect to database by connector

Answer (score 5):

JDBC is a library used by your Java programs to access relational databases. You can use it to access Oracle, Informix, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, DB2, and other makes  of database server, as well as MySQL.

The MySQL connector is a library for, well, connecting JDBC to the MySQL database. If your program were using Oracle, you would use the Oracle connector instead.

This is necessary because each make of database server has its own specific protocol for transporting requests to, and results from, the server to application programs.

Comment: What about the version of connector and version of MySQL database server, how should we take care of it? F.i. I see the connector version is lower than the server version (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';)

Comment: Don't worry about matching connector and server versions unless your server is really ancient (v4 or earlier).

Comment: Thanks. But basically, can the server have an older version than the connector? Would it work, what are the limits here? I just want to understand fully :)